# how to get started with viper/vimpulse?

Tags: emacs, viper-mode, vimpulse

I obtained a git clone of vimpulse and followed the instructions for installation. It basically says to put `(require 'vimpulse)` in my .emacs file - but this will start viper/vimpulse upon startup, so I tried to have vimpulse load only if I invoke viper-mode with `(add-hook 'viper-mode-hook (lambda () (require 'vimpuse))`. But when I do this visual mode does not work (tries to open file instead), so instead I now have something like `(defun vimpulse-on () (interactive) (require 'vimpulse))`. After that to toggle on and off I use `C-z`. Does that about sound right? So once vimpulse is loaded there's no equivalent of `M-x viper-go-away` and instead it's suspended until I hit `C-z` again... Also, any general tips with using viper/vimpulse would be appreciated! Thanks much in advance.

*Edit:* syntax error corrected. What I had tried was `(add-hook 'viper-mode-hook (lambda () (require 'vimpulse))`, which does not enable visual mode when `viper-mode` is started. `v` in normal-mode appears to be mapped to `find-file` (or `ido-find-file`).

Comment: Even if I suspend vimpulse for a particular buffer `C-z`, vimpulse is enabled for new buffers by default...

Comment: A feature is only loaded at the first `require'. Later `require' will do nothing if it's loaded.

Comment: Yes, I call `require` only once. But it seems like I can do `C-z` to switch to vi-state and then do `M-x viper-go-away` to make it stop.

Answer (score 1):

```
(add-hook 'viper-load-hook
   (lambda () (require 'vimpulse))
```

Just load vimpulse in the viper-load-hook.

Comment: Actually this is what I tried (sorry, syntax error in my post), I did add the `require` statement to `viper-mode-hook`, but then `visual-mode` does not work when `viper-mode` is enabled. And loading `vimpulse` will already load `viper-mode`.

Comment: I can't find `viper-mode-hook' in my Emacs 23.2.1. Make sure you have loaded vimpulse in the right place (or manually), then check the function `vimpulse-visual-toggle-normal' which should be bound to v in vimpulse, if not found, make sure you have the latest vimpulse at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/vimpulse.el